# Replace a digit with [0-9] in R

Tags: r, regex

When using R, I would like to replace the last digit, and all digits before the character `|`, with a `[0-9]` for further searching in another dataframe.

For example in `chr8:79868538|79889059` the outcome should be like this: `chr8:7986853[0-9]|7988905[0-9]`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure about the syntax in R but generally, you'd replace `\d(\||$)` with something like `[0-9]\1`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/aA21ij/1).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `gsub` like :

```
string <- "chr8:79868538|79889059"
gsub("\\d(?=\\|)|\\d$", '[0-9]', string, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "chr8:7986853[0-9]|7988905[0-9]"
```

The same regex can also be used with `str_replace_all` from `stringr`

```
stringr::str_replace_all(string, "\\d(?=\\|)|\\d$", '[0-9]')
```

This will replace the last digit which is followed by `|` OR the last number in the string with `'[0-9]'`.

Comment: Won't `.` match characters that are not digits as well?

Comment: Yes, it will but I assumed OP would always have digits there. Nonetheless, you are correct I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
gsub("(\\d)(\\||$)", "[0-9]\\2", "chr8:79868538|79889059")
#[1] "chr8:7986853[0-9]|7988905[0-9]"
```